# Как остановить requestAnimationFrame и получить уникальный progress

Tags: javascript, анимация

Я хочу сделать так, чтобы при клике анимация, которая идёт, заканчивалась, и в переменную записывалась информация, на каком прогрессе анимация закончилась.
И потом запустить анимацию с тем прогрессом, который был до этого.

У меня получается так: при быстром клике два раза можно заметить, что происходит быстрая анимация, а потом уже медленная доходит, так как я её не остановил.

Я не понимаю, как получить значение progress из функции и как правильно заканчивать анимацию.

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("second");

function animate({timing, draw, duration}) {

let start = performance.now();

requestAnimationFrame(function animate(time) {
 let timeFraction = (time - start) / duration;
 if (timeFraction > 1) {
  timeFraction = 1;
 }
 let progress = timing(timeFraction);

 draw(progress);
 if (timeFraction < 1) {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
 }
});
}

var num = 0;

window.addEventListener('click', () => {

if (num == 0) {
 animate({
        duration: 800,
        timing: function(timeFraction) {
          return timeFraction;
        },
        draw: function(progress) {
         elem.style.marginLeft = progress * 500 + 'px';
     }
  });
  num = 1;
} else {
 animate({
        duration: 2000,
        timing: function(timeFraction) {
          return timeFraction;
        },
        draw: function(progress) {
         elem.style.marginLeft = (1 - progress) * 500 + 'px';
     }
  });
  num = 0;
}

});
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
}

#second {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 position: relative;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="second"></div>
```

UPD:
Я понял как заканчивать анимацию при запуске новой, нужно просто использовать cancelAnimationFrame(requestId), а в аргументе должна быть переменная, в которую записывался requestAnimationFrame
Но я плохо понимаю, как получать значение progress, так как он получается из функции, `progress = timing(timeFraction);`, не понимая как сюда втиснуть моё значение.

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("first");
var myReq;
var progress;

function animate({timing, draw, duration}) {

 let start = performance.now();

 requestAnimationFrame(function animate(time) {

  let timeFraction = (time - start) / duration;
  if (timeFraction > 1) {
   timeFraction = 1;
  }
  progress = timing(timeFraction);
  draw(progress);
  if (timeFraction < 1) {
   myReq = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  }

 });
}



var num = 0;

window.addEventListener('click', () => {

 cancelAnimationFrame(myReq);

 if (num == 0) {
  animate({
         duration: 800,
         timing: function(timeFraction) {
           return timeFraction;
         },
         draw: function(progress) {
          elem.style.marginLeft = progress * 500 + 'px';
         }
      });
      num = 1;
 } else {
  animate({
         duration: 2000,
         timing: function(timeFraction) {
           return timeFraction;
         },
         draw: function(progress) {
          elem.style.marginLeft = (1 - progress) * 500 + 'px';
         }
      });
      num = 0;
 }

});
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}

#first{
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 position: relative;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="first"></div>
```

Comment: я мало что понял

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я хочу сделать так, чтобы при клике анимация шла в другую сторону. К примеру: круг идёт вправо, а на половине пути происходит клик и круг начинает идти влево из того места, где круг был. Использовал request по инфе отсюда https://learn.javascript.ru/js-animation , но тут нету пояснений как управлять анимацией на разных позициях

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня получилось сделать, но с другой логикой:

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("first");
var gameEngine;
var x = 0;
var nameFunc;
var reqAnimFrame = (function() {
 return requestAnimationFrame       ||
        mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
        webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        oRequestAnimationFrame      ||
        msRequestAnimationFrame     ||
 function(callback) {
     setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    }
})();

function gameEngineStart(callback) {
 gameEngine = callback;
 gameEngineStep();
}

function gameEngineStep() {
 reqAnimFrame(gameEngineStep);
 gameEngine();
}

function setGameEngine(callback) {
 gameEngine = callback;
}

function gameLoopLeft() {
 elem.style.marginLeft = x + 'px';
 x += 2;
 if (x >= 300) {
  setGameEngine(gameLoopRight);
  nameFunc = 'gameLoopRight';
 }
}

function gameLoopRight() {
 x -= 2;
 elem.style.marginLeft = x + 'px';
 if (x <= 0) {
  setGameEngine(gameLoopLeft);
  nameFunc = 'gameLoopLeft';
 }
}

gameEngineStart(gameLoopLeft);

window.addEventListener('click', () => {

 if (nameFunc == 'gameLoopLeft') {
  setGameEngine(gameLoopRight);
  nameFunc = 'gameLoopRight';
 } else {
  setGameEngine(gameLoopLeft);
  nameFunc = 'gameLoopLeft';
 }

});
```

```css
#first{
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 position: relative;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="first"></div>
```